# How to retrieve characteristics attributes of a product in Magento 2 GraphQL API based on their attribute set?

Tags: magento2, attribute-set, graphql, mobile, magento-product-attributes

In Magento 2, each product can be assigned with an attribute set, which varies based on the product category. My attribute set contains specific characteristics such as color and manufacturer, which I want to display on the frontend in the more information section. I am developing a mobile application using Magento 2 GraphQL API and need to retrieve the specific product attributes that are designated as characteristics of the product based on their attribute set. However, currently, I only have the attribute_set_id, which is not helping me. How can I solve this problem and retrieve the characteristics attributes of a product in Magento 2 GraphQL API based on their attribute set?

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve characteristics attributes of a product in Magento 2 GraphQL API based on their attribute set, you need to use the products query along with the desired filters and attributes.

Here is a step-by-step guide on how to do this:

First, get the attribute set ID. You can do this by going to your Magento Admin Panel and navigating to Stores > Attributes > Attribute Set. Find the attribute set you are interested in and note down its ID.

Next, prepare the GraphQL query to fetch the products based on the attribute set ID. Here's an example of the GraphQL query:

```
    query {
  products(
    filter: {
      attribute_set_id: {
        eq: "ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID"
      }
    },
    pageSize: 10,
    currentPage: 1
  ) {
    items {
      id
      sku
      name
      attribute_set_id
      custom_attributes: customAttributeMetadata(filter: {attribute_set_id: "ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID"}) {
        items {
          attribute_code
          attribute_type
        }
      }
    }
    total_count
  }
}
```

Replace ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID with the actual attribute set ID you found in step 1.

Send the GraphQL query to your Magento 2 GraphQL API endpoint. The default endpoint URL is typically http://your-magento-store-url/graphql.

Parse the JSON response to extract the required data, such as the product attributes and their values.

Here's a breakdown of the GraphQL query:

```
products is the main query to fetch the products.
The filter parameter is used to filter the products based on the attribute set ID.
The pageSize and currentPage parameters are used for pagination.
The items field returns a list of products with the specified attributes, such as id, sku, name, and attribute_set_id.
The custom_attributes alias is used to fetch the custom attributes for the specified attribute set, including their attribute_code and attribute_type.
Finally, the total_count field returns the total number of products that match the filter.
```

By using this GraphQL query, you can retrieve the characteristic attributes of a product based on their attribute set in Magento 2 GraphQL API.

Comment: In my case the attribite_set_id filter and the custom_attributes field are missing and cannot be used. Any suggestions? Thank you for the answer.

Comment: I have to ask how they could be missing and why can't you expose them?